# Able to remove non-editable text in CKEditor by using right and left scroll

Tags: ckeditor

I have some text in CKEditor which should be editable and some text which should be non-editable.

The non-editable text I am enclosing in a span as below.

```
<span contenteditable="false" unselectable="on">Here is where my non-editable text goes</span>
```

The editable text I am enclosing in a span as below.

```
<span style="background-color:Yellow">$[insert Date]</span>
```

Here we are using style background yellow to highlight the editable text in yellow to the user.

I put my cursor within the editable text and move using the left or right arrow keys. Once I move outside the editable text area, I am able to remove even the non-editable text using backspace.

The issue is that as soon as my cursor moves outside the editable text area the code isn't able to detect any key press due to which I am not able to restrict the backspace or delete.

Does Range functionality help in this issue? If yes please help and give an example of where we can use the Range code.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

It came to my attention that there is a $nonEditable dtd descriptor that could also come in handy:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dtd.html
https://ckeditor.com/old//forums/CKEditor-3.x/Forcing-custom-element-be-BLOCK-level-element

**PREVIOUS:**
You could use the widget functionality to make the text ineditable-- using contenteditable="false" in CKEditor can be a bit unpredictable, but the creating a widget extension plugin can have really nice results.

It would be a very basic widget that simply uses the [upcast](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1.html#how-does-a-widget-become-a-widget) checking if the element has 'unselectable="on"', then the text will automatically become uneditable and using the arrow keys will simply skip over the text instead of entering it. You also get quite a bit of other functionality with the widget plugin and it makes it much easier to integrate into things like events, dialog editing, etc.

You can get a widget creation tutorial here:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1.html

For more information, I just answered a question about making parts ineditable here:

[How can I create uneditable fields on CK Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879089/how-can-i-create-uneditable-fields-on-ck-editor/48881066#48881066)